# Android background thread that updates the UI in multiple activities

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm very new to Android, this is my first app. I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

I am building an app that will query a server over tcp/ip every minute. I would like to show the status of this server (up/down) at the top of every activity/screen.

My questions are:

1) What should I use to continuously ping a server in the background across multiple activities? For instance, is there a way to spawn a thread from one activity in such a way that it will continue even if the user goes to a different screen?

2) How can I allow this thread to update a status label on whatever screen the user happens to be viewing?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use services. Please get familiar with documentation first.
2. You can use service binding or local broadcast messaging to notify your current/front activity about changes from your service